# Need help installing curl on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, xubuntu

After entering

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

I get the message

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
curl : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.47.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I haven't the clue what this means or how to go about fixing it, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: @steeldriver. It doesn't help

Answer (score 14):

You can install the specified libcurl version with:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-gnutls=7.47.0-1ubuntu2
```

and then install curl

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install curl
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: THanks a lot!! You were great!!